# Change plugin template in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress plugin with template file. And this file has function

```
function parse_smart_content_func($atts, $content){
...
$html .= '<div class="smart-box-content">';
            if($layout!='medium_carousel_2'){
                $html .= '<div class="smart-item '.$class_cssit.'">
                    <div class="row">';
            }
....
```

And I want to change this function. But if I update plugin I will lost my code. 
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to copy the template file from the plugin in your theme. The version in our theme should overwrite the one in the plugin.
To know how to name it, use this diagram of wordpress theme:

http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Fpp